# Pandas: Find row containing several values arbitrarily distributed over columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking for a nice solution to the following problem: I've got a a pandas DataFrame from which I only know that one of the rows contains several values that are arbitrarily distributed over the columns. I'd like to find that row.

Example:
Both of the following two dataframes have exactly one row that contains the values 'hey', 'here' and 'I am':

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": (np.nan, 1, "hey", 5, 100), "b": ("testing", np.nan, "here", "what", -3),
                   "c": (1, "two", 3, "four", 5), "d": ("ay", "why", "I am", np.nan, 4)})
```

```
df:
     a        b     c     d
0  NaN  testing     1    ay
1    1      NaN   two   why
2  hey     here     3  I am
3    5     what  four   NaN
4  100       -3     5     4
```

In df row 2 (third row) contains the values 'hey', 'here' and 'I am'.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": (np.nan, 1, np.nan, 5, "I am"), "b": ("testing", np.nan, "something", "what", -3),
                    "c": (1, "two", 3, "four", "hey"), "d": ("ay", "why", "I am", np.nan, "here")})
```

```
df2:
      a          b     c     d
0   NaN    testing     1    ay
1     1        NaN   two   why
2   NaN  something     3  I am
3     5       what  four   NaN
4  I am         -3   hey  here
```

In df2 row 4 (fifth row) contains the values 'hey', 'here' and 'I am'.

How do I get the row index of the corresponding row containing the values?
My solution works but it is ugly:

```
row_id = [id for id, row in df.iterrows() if hasattr(row, "str") and
          (row.str.contains("hey").sum() +
           row.str.contains("here").sum() +
           row.str.contains("I am").sum() == 3)][0]
```

I guess that there has to be a nicer and more pythonic solution to that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pythonic way to approach the problem. Mask the values which are not in the list `l`, then use `nunique` along the columns axis to count the unique values and compare the count with `3` to create a boolean mask

```
l = ['hey', 'here', 'I am']
s = df.where(df.isin(l)).nunique(axis=1).eq(3)
```

---

```
print(s)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool

print(s[s].index)
Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')
```